# Type inference and Type checking

Tags: type-theory, type-checking, dependent-types, type-inference

I understand that adding the annotations (dependent typing) may cause the type checking of the programming language to become undecidable.

What about type inference ?

Whether type checking and type inference of Agda  is undecidable ?

I'm interested not only in type checking but type inference also.

Comment: The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Comment: 1. Your question is very broad.  It sounds like you are asking for a survey of an entire area (decidability for a whole bunch of languages.  I suggest you edit your question to narrow it down -- e.g., to ask about a single type system or language, and a single task (either type checking or type inference; pick one).  2. What research have you done?  There's lots of literature on this.  3. Obviously type inference is at least as hard as type checking.

Comment: [Conor McBride says](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4634303/dependently-typed-language-best-suited-to-real-world-programming): "Typechecking in Agda is decidable unless you switch off positivity/termination/universe checking".

Comment: See this question: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/12691/what-makes-type-inference-for-dependent-types-undecidable